# How can I get a Santa Strike?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How can I get a Santa Strike in Clash of Clans?

Answer (score 2):

The [Santa Strike](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Santa_Strike) is a trap that was exclusive to the Christmas update in 2013.  It's no longer available, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the "Santa Strike" as it was for a limited time only in a Christmas update. The only way to have one is if you saved one and haven't used it ever since then.